# Inferring type parameters

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-parameter

I am integrating with some java api, that looks kinda like this (these are java classes, I'll just use scala syntax for brevity:

```
 class AbstractFooBuilder[ActualType <: AbstractFooBuilder, WhatToBuild <: Foo] {
     // ... 
     def withFoo(f: Foo): ActualType
     def withBar(b: Bar): ActualType
     // ...
     def build: WhatToBuild          
 }

 class FooBarBuilder extends AbstractFooBuilder[FooBarBuilder, FooBar]
 class FooBazBuilder extends AbstractFooBuilder[FooBazBuilder, FooBaz]
 // .. etc
```

There is a bunch of these, and I am trying to make the creation of these foos less repetitive with something like this:

```
def anyFoo[T <: Foo, B <: AbstractFooBuilder[B, T] : Manifest](foo: Foo, b: Bar) = manifest
  .runtimeClass
  .newInstance
  .withFoo(foo)
  .withBar(bar)
  .build
```

The problem is, that now, to create `FooBar`, I have to write something like this:

```
 val foobar = new anyFoo[FooBar, FooBarBuilder](foo, bar)
```

which is longer than I would like. Specifically, once `FooBarBuilder` type parameter is known, `FooBar`is the only possibility for the second param ... I wonder if there is some trick I am missing, that would make it possible to "infer" the other param, and only have to specify one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the standard trick to split the type parameters doesn't work here because `B` depends on `T`.

But what about getting rid of `Manifest` and simplifying to

```
def anyFoo[T <: Foo](builder: AbstractFooBuilder[_, T])(foo: Foo, b: Bar) = 
  builder.withBar(b).withFoo(foo).build
```

? You call it as `anyFoo(new FooBarBuilder)(foo, b)`, so `T` is inferred, solving your problem. And as a bonus, it's faster and there is no runtime error if your class happens not to have a default constructor.

If your method didn't always need to create the builder, you could use by-name parameter or `() => AbstractFooBuilder[_, T]`.

EDIT: Given the comment, this could work:

```
def mkBuilder[B <: AbstractFooBuilder[B, _] : Manifest]: B = // the complex creation code

anyFoo(mkBuilder[FooBarBuilder])(foo, b) // infers FooBar
```

The question is whether you can implement `mkBuilder` without access to `T`, but if your original code doesn't need a `Manifest[T]`, it should be possible.

Or even

```
implicit class AnyFoo[T, B <: AbstractFooBuilder[B, T]](builder: B) {
  def apply(foo: Foo, b: Bar) = builder.withBar(b).withFoo(foo).build
}

mkBuilder[FooBarBuilder](foo, b)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing ... It's unfortunate, because creating the builder itself is rather tedious in reality, not just `new Builder` as I simplified it in the question, and I wanted for the caller to be able to avoid having to do it everywhere. Oh well ...

Comment: Yeah, that works ... although, not much shorter, than `anyFoo[Foo, FooBarBuilder](foo, b)`, but not as ugly :)

Comment: Yet another edit :) I am not certain it'll work, but expect that it should.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading code correctly. The code does not imply there is only one `AbstractFooBuilder` factory for this type and this is left to the caller to specify the factory to use.

If you can use implicit, you can do something like this

```
def anyFoo[T <: Foo](foo: Foo, b: Bar)(implicit factory: AbstractFooBuilder[T]): T = {
         factory.
             withBar(b).
             withFoo(foo).
             build
}
```

Comment: Yes, the caller has to specify the factory, but it feels, like it should be possible to avoid _also_ having to specify the type of the object, that it builds, because that is determined by the factory type.